# Counting user request in Service Contract

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, throttling

I am developing a WCF service that has to process only one user request at a time. Other request has to be queued up and if the queue gets big then then other request are stored in the database and users are notified accordingly. I was able to get user queue by implementing service throttling in WCF but users gets request timed out error when the queue is long. For request throttling I used WCF service throttling on service contract 2.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
```

But for Service Contract 1, I have implemented

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

I tried  counting the pending request from WCF throttling service, but it seems there is no such method that gives current queue list in WCF.

1. Is there any method that can count the queue list in another service
   contract.
2. Do I have to change my design to implement this flow in WCF service.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Under IIS manager, Application Pools -> Advanced Settings you can set the Queue length to something larger as needed:
[image]

Comment: Setting the queue length does not allow me to count the number of request currently in the queue at the runtime.

Comment: The only other suggestion would be to put all requests in service contract 2 in a db or arraylist, and then query the count of records.

Comment: Yes I also tried implementing that but since it handles only one request at a time, all other request has to be put on hold status as I have to implement direct download function too. If it was not needed (direct download), I can do DB implementation and process one request at a time.
Another option would be capturing storing user request on a runtime, processing it and put it in result table and implement the user response function. But I have no idea capturing user request and sending response manually in WCF.